# deleting all files in a directory with no extension with python

Tags: python, file, delete-file

I am on a mac, I granted permissions to my desktop (which is where the files are) I run it and it detects the files and the if statement works but they are not in fact deleted

```
 import glob
 import os 
 import os.path


 def testThingy(system_path):
      for file in glob.glob(system_path+"/*"): print(file, " this will be deleted")
      if input("continue ? ") == "Y":
          for file in glob.glob(system_path+"/*"): os.remove(file)
```

is it just a mac thing? or is there something missing in my code

Comment: You probably want to fix your post so your code is indented exactly the same as your real script (which is _particularly_ important when it comes to Python questions =)

Comment: It is exactly as it is in the script the system path is just a string to your system path

Comment: In that case you'll want to format your code a little to follow Python conventions first, with those `print` and `os.remove` instructions on their own line, not immediately following the colon. Having said that: what's `system_path`? I.e. you're showing a piece of code that can't run on its own, can you show your code in [mcve] form and talk about what you're seeing it do (e.g. show what output you get when you run it).

Comment: I think os.listdir from os package solves your problem. Just make something like ```for file_name in os.listdir(full_path):``` and use  ```os.remove(os.path.join(full_path,file_name))```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```py
import pathlib
system_path = pathlib.Path(".")  # enter your actual directory
to_be_deleted = [path for path in system_path.glob("*") if path.is_file() and path.suffix == "" and not str(path).startswith(".")]
print(to_be_deleted)

if input("continue ? ") == "Y":
     for i in to_be_deleted:
         i.unlink()
```

The `if` clause

```py
path.is_file() and path.suffix == "" and not str(path).startswith(".")
```

filters paths, such that we don't try delete directories `path.is_file()`, the file doesn't have an extension `path.suffix == ""` and is not a "hidden" file `not str(path).startswith(".")`.

You could use [`path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to search directories recursively.